# После обновления не работает маршрутизатор

Tags: yandex-maps-api

```
var map;
ymaps.ready(function(){
var mapDivId = 'map'; //Id контейнера для карты 
var mapCenter = [55.76, 37.64]; //Координата центра карты по умолчанию
map = new ymaps.Map(mapDivId , { center: mapCenter, zoom: 10 });

var pointA = "Саратов"; //Откуда считаем
var pointB = "Москва"; //Куда считаем
ymaps.route([pointA , pointB ]).then(
  function (route) {
     var distance = route.getHumanLength(); //Получаем расстояние
     alert(distance.replace(' ', ' '));
     map.geoObjects.add(route); //Рисуем маршрут на карте
  },
  function (error) {
     alert('Ошибка: ' + error.message); 
  }
);
});
```

Этот код выводит "Bad response". До обновления до версии 2.1.64 все работало.
API подключаю такой ссылкой:
    https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU
(прямо как в документации)

Comment: У меня маршрут построился: https://jsfiddle.net/yu1hd2y6/ Возможно, проблема именно с вашим ip адресом/сайтом - напишите лучше в саппорт API

Comment: @Reni сниппеты и здесь делать можно. зачем их выносить на фиддл?

Comment: @teran можно и здесь, конечно, просто дебажить/редактировать удобнее на внешнем ресурсе

Comment: @Reni, в саппорте ответили писать сюда. код по ссылке тоже построился. Это странно. Полностью скопированный код себе - выводит 'bad response'. до обновления все работало!

Comment: @Reni, сайт - просто проект, он локальный, проблема с ip адресом - с разных ip не работает, и на нескольких машинах проверял

Comment: @Никита какой статус ответа? какой текст ошибки? проект локальный на стадии разработки или всегда задуман работать локально? могла сработать блокировка за превышение запросов/нарушение условий использования. Очевидно, что технической проблемы с API - нет, потому что код рабочий, а проблема где-то локально. На такие вопросы отвечает саппорт :)

Comment: @Reni, текст ошибки как раз "bad response", код ошибки, не поверите, "undefind") это мой дипломный проект, и дальше локалки вряд ли продвинется. по поводу блокировки или превышения лимита запросов - не подходит. я ж говорю: все сломалось после обновления. Сейчас я принудительно в проекте указал версию 2.1.62 - и все работает, 2.1.63 и 2.1.64 - нет - вот что интересно. просто прога не дописана, через неделю сдача диплома, а тут API перестает работать)
P.S.: ОС windows7
P.P.S.: буду использовать версию 2.1.62